# Adeles for function fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, function-fields, adeles

Usually the ring of adeles is defined for number fields: if $K$ is a number field the ring of adeles of $K$ is:

$$\mathbb A_K:=\prod_{v}' K_v    \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(\ast)$$

where $v$ ranges among all valuations (archimedian and non-archimedian) and $\prod'$ is the restricted product with respect to the valuation rings $\mathcal O_v$. With $K_v$ I mean the completion of $K$ with respect to $v$.

Now suppose that $K$ is an algebraic function field over $k$, is it true that  the adelic ring is defined as in the equation $(\ast)$ but with the difference that $v$ **ranges among all valuations which are trivial on $k$**?

I think that we need to add this restriction on $v$ in order to preserve the correspondence with the closed point of the projective curve $X$ such that $K(X)=K$.

Comment: What do you mean by $k$ here?  The finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$, or $\mathbb{F}_q(T)$, or something else?

Comment: $k$ is any field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that $k$ is algebraically closed in $K$, a valuation of $K$ is indeed trivial on $k^\times$.  Please see page 13 of [here](http://press.princeton.edu/chapters/s9103.pdf) for a detailed description.

However, usually when constructing the adeles, $K$ is assumed to be a global field.  A *global function field* is defined over  a *finite* field $k$, in which case the triviality of the valuation on $k^\times$ is automatic.